# Integrating GeoExt 2.0 with Sencha Architect 3

Tags: extjs, sencha-architect, geoext

**Does anyone know the best way to go about integrating GeoExt 2.0 into Sencha Architect 3?**

It seems like it is possible but there is not a very clear way to do it based on some of the documentation I have looked at.

A forum post here([GeoExt Inside Sencha Architect](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?259458-Geoext-inside-Sencha-Architect)) on Sencha's forums mentions adding GeoExt as an external resource then instantianting classes inside Sencha architect from the resource.  I followed the links in the post and it takes you Sencha's user guide for using resources.

Based on this information here I should be able to do the following.

- Add GeoExt Map Panel as a resource
- Place a panel in my view
- Set the extend property on the panel I just placed to be GeoExtMapPanel.

However, I am not finding an extend property.

The other option I have looked into is possibly creating Architect Extension definitions for GeoExt components that I want to use.  This option does seem more involved.  There is a guide on creating a user extension here([Creating an Architect Extension](http://www.sencha.com/blog/building-a-user-extension-and-integrating-it-into-sencha-architect-3-part-1)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use the extend property you'll need to create a Class not a Panel.